# How can I downgrade from PHP 7.2 to PHP 5.6 EC2 linux

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I am new to Ec2. Where  i have installed php 7. Php is running on ec2. But my php files are in 5.6. So whether running the file in php in ec2 linux. Its not working. 
So i have decide to downgrade php 7.2 to php 5.6.

How to Downgrade it. or else  How can i uninstall php 7. and reinstall php 5.6.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Is it running apache? Nginx? It's possible to have multiple versions of PHP on a server and use server directives to select which version is executed in various parts of the server. If you want to run everything on 5.6 you could do away with PHP 7, but it's probably worth keeping around for future development.

Comment: What is the linux version you are using? Is it Ubuntu?

Comment: I am working in Ec2  Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo).Running Apache...

Comment: @cloudfire you should add this info to the question that it's Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple versions of PHP running on Linux.

```
$ sudo apt install php5.6 
$ sudo apt install php7.0 
$ sudo apt install php7.1
```

Use the update-alternative command to switch and set the default version of PHP you want to run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Then confirm:

```
php -v
```

Comment: sudo apt install php5.6   this command is not working... But i have run this command    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6 . It Executed Successfully...But when i run php 5.6 it shows error.

Comment: set locale, defaulting to C
It shows the Error 
Loading Plugins: extras_suggestions,langapacks,priorities,update-motd

file contains no section headers

Answer (score 2):

You could use remi repository. Try with these commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y update
sudo yum -y install amazon-linux-extras
sudo yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum -y install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56 
sudo yum -y install php56-gd php56-curl php56-mysql php56-ldap php56-zip php56-fileinfo php56-php-pecl-zip
sudo scl enable php56 bash
```

You can find a complete guide in this link https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-5-6-on-centos-7/